# How to show the DropDownList component in Flex DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I am very new to flex. I have successfully added a dropDownList in my dataGrid table.The dropdownList works fine. Its just that since I am doing this for the user. I want to be able to see the dropDowList component/Icon itself in the dataGrid table, instead of me clicking the cell and then the dropDownList appears for me to select. Is it possible for me to achieve this?? Must I use flex skin or something ? Pls guide me on how can I can achieve this and pls if possible give me an example.

Thanks
Rekha

This is the code I have right now:

```
 <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[                
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        [Bindable]
        private var myDP:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {label1:"Order #2314", quant:3, color:'red'},
            {label1:"Order #2315", quant:3, color:'red'}                
        ]);         
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:DataGrid id="myDG" x="29" y="33" width="393" height="151" dataProvider="{myDP}"
            editable="true" variableRowHeight="true">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="label1" headerText="Order #" editable="false"/>                
            <s:GridColumn dataField="quant" headerText="Qty" editable="true"/>

            <s:GridColumn dataField="color" headerText="Color" editable="true">                     
                <s:itemEditor>
                    <fx:Component>                              
                        <s:GridItemEditor>              
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[

                                    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
                                    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                                    import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

                                    override public function set value(newValue:Object):void {

                                        cb.selectedItem = newValue;
                                    }

                                    override public function get value():Object {
                                        return cb.selectedItem.toString();
                                    }

                                    override public function setFocus():void {
                                        cb.setFocus();
                                    }

                                    override public function save():Boolean
                                    {
                                        data[column.dataField] = value;                                     
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                            <s:DropDownList id="cb" requireSelection="true" skinClass="MySkins.mytestddbSkin">
                                <s:dataProvider>
                                    <s:ArrayCollection>
                                        <fx:String>red</fx:String>
                                        <fx:String>blue</fx:String>
                                        <fx:String>green</fx:String>
                                    </s:ArrayCollection>                                        
                                </s:dataProvider>
                            </s:DropDownList>                               
                        </s:GridItemEditor>                         
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemEditor>             
            </s:GridColumn> 

        </s:ArrayList> 
    </s:columns >
</s:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ItemRenderer instead of the ItemEditor. In this case you should set rendererIsEditable property of the GridColumn to true.

Then you can use the change event of the DropDownList, to register the change in your data provider.

I have added the color column twice to let you see, that the data is actually edited after the selection.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[                
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]private var myDP:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {label1:"Order #2314", quant:3, color:'red'},
            {label1:"Order #2315", quant:3, color:'red'}                
        ]);         
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:DataGrid id="myDG" x="29" y="33" height="151" dataProvider="{myDP}"
            editable="true" variableRowHeight="true">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="label1" headerText="Order #" editable="false"/>                
            <s:GridColumn dataField="quant" headerText="Qty" editable="true"/>

            <s:GridColumn dataField="color" headerText="Color" editable="true" width="120"/>       

            <s:GridColumn dataField="color" headerText="Color" editable="true" rendererIsEditable="true" width="180">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <s:GridItemRenderer>
                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[
                                import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

                                protected function onCbChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
                                {
                                    var value:String = (event.currentTarget as DropDownList).selectedItem;
                                    data[column.dataField] = value; 
                                }
                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>

                        <s:DropDownList id="cb" requireSelection="true" width="100%" change="onCbChange(event)">
                            <s:dataProvider>
                                <s:ArrayCollection>
                                    <fx:String>red</fx:String>
                                    <fx:String>blue</fx:String>
                                    <fx:String>green</fx:String>
                                </s:ArrayCollection>                                        
                            </s:dataProvider>
                        </s:DropDownList>   

                    </s:GridItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>

        </s:ArrayList> 
    </s:columns >
</s:DataGrid>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ! this really helped.I really appreciate it. But what if I want to get the value without touching the dropdownlist ? say red is the colour I want since its already showing. The user wont change it. Is there a away of doing that ? Plus I wanted to ask u

Comment: Plus I wanted to ask u if u see my codes above there are some override methods like getValue setValue and save for the dropDown list How do I know such methods exist for me to override them ? where can I find these methods? I tried to right click the <s:GridItemEditor> then went to source>override methods.I didt see any methods called get, set value or save . Pls I tried reading textbooks and online flex help.I still cant seem to figure out. Thankyou so much one again. :)

Comment: Hi! To your second question: as far as I know, you can't see overridable methods if you use inline renderers. I think the list of methods is generated from the Application scope. Instead you can try to use an external renderer and then you will see its methods very well through "source>override methods menu".

Comment: To the first question: do you mean either or not you can read the value without user interaction? You can always appeal to your data model (in your case myDP) and read its values like this: myDP.getItemAt(1).color. If I have misunderstood your question, please explain me it more specific.

Comment: hi ! yes I was trying to ask u if I can read the value in the drop down list *when* there is no user interaction. So If the first value in the drop down list is red, and the user wants red, then he will not interact with the drop down list. How can I capture the value in the drop down list when this happens ? How can i know that he didt trigger the drop down list so that i can take red as my value ? Pls let me know if its not clear.I will try to rephrase. Thanks soo much. :

Comment: The value is always available from your dataprovider, you jaust have to determin the number of record (say "i") and the name of the data field. Something like this: myDP.getItemAt(i).color. You can do it at any point in time if your dataprovider has been initialized. Is it what you wanted to know?

Comment: Yes! got it! U answered what i wanted to know! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks once again.